# Quick update of what's new in Java in the last 5 years?

Tags: java, education

It's been 5 years since I worked with Java, but I'm in the job market again and there seem to be more Java positions than C/C++ where I live now. Are there any resources to quickly come back up to speed? The last Java I developed with was 1.3.

Also what are the good resources for java technologies like springs and struts?

Comment: To be fair, Spring and Struts are very popular frameworks and libraries, but they are not part of Java.

Comment: The sad thing about Java is that *it is* in fact possible to give a quick update about its evolution in 5 years. Much harder to do that with languages that don't evolve as glacially.

Comment: The only things that are new in the past 5 years are version 6 and the purchase of Sun by Oracle, but if you last programmed in Java 1.3 you need to catch up on the past *11* years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most important new features:

Language:

1. C++ template style Generics
2. Enumerations
3. Variable Arguments
4. Autoboxing

API:

1. New concurrency packages
2. New JavaBeans package
3. New Compilation packages

Features:

1. Great support for Web Services
2. Huge performance improvements

Comment: 1. Generics (compile time type erasure makes it very much unlike C++ style generics)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the official Oracle pages are a good start to quickly gauge new features in Java [4](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/relnotes/features.html) [to](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html) [6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/features-141434.html). [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) and [Struts](http://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsTutorials) too have their own tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

For Java updates/features, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003346/what-is-difference-between-jdk-1-4-and-jdk1-6) question. Also, visit the [OTN for Java Developers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html) site.

For Spring, the best resource is the [official Spring site](http://www.springsource.org).